# Can my Pea Soup Slime Monster Exist?

Tags: creature-design, mythical-creatures

Peasoupers are acidic, bright green slime monsters that smell a lot like snap pea jelly (I assume, I’ve never smelled snap pea jelly). They are deaf, but can see, taste and feel. On average, Peasoupers are the size of a human head, though they can squeeze through any hole larger than four inches wide. Basically, they are giant amoeboids. They eat through their skin/membrane, and excrete a corrosive fluid that can dissolve wood, flesh, fabric, and bone. This acid is sticky, and if a Peasouper encounters something it can’t dissolve, it can crawl up it. So, given this criteria, my question is thus: **can Peasoupers feasibly exist?**

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Our [help/on-topic] states that our focus is to help you build an imaginary world. In your imaginary world, the answer to "Is X feasible?" is always "yes." If you're trying to invent a creature that could hypothetically exist in the Real World, this gem has some serious problems. Like an acid that, in the Real World, would destroy the peasouper. We're happy to help you design your creature, but you've not asked a question about a problem with your cretaure. Do you have a problem we can help you with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short Answer: Yes**

This monster is perfectly feasible. Provided you make it clear to the reader that your world works by different laws to the real world. It is full of creatures that would not be able to move or survive if you put them on Earth. Problem solved.

---

**Long Answer: Of course not.**

This is an unbelievable monster. To make it "feasible" you must drop many of the sillier properties. You get the remaining properties by combining powers from two real animals -- the mighty slug and the crafty octopus. These two guys are both molluscs so it is not unbelievable to combine their powers.

[image]

Pea-soupers are a type of land-slug-topus. They are squishy and slimy and smell like snap peas. They can climb up walls and squeeze through pipes. They can slowly dissolve garbage and dead bodies. But they cannot melt a hole in the castle gate or chase adventurers down a hallway.

> bright green slime monsters that smell a lot like snap pea jelly (I assume, I’ve never smelled snap pea jelly).

There exist bright green sea slugs. I am not sure about the smell but it sounds believable next to the other things on this list. I suggest the green comes from symbiotic photosynthetic bacteria and the smell comes from symbiotic photosynthetic bacteria.

> They are deaf, but can see, taste and feel.

Like a slug. Have you ever startled a slug by shouting? Thought not.

> Peasoupers are the size of a human head

Comfortably inside the size range of an octopus.

> they can squeeze through any hole larger than four inches wide.

[Octopusses can to this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=99Vc69tMU98)

> Basically, they are giant amoeboids.

This is a silly part. Giant amoebids exist. They are called slime molds. They have no internal anatomy and cannot move. If you poke them they leak.

> They eat through their skin/membrane

There is no large creature that eats through its skin. Large creatures have specialized organs.

> excrete a corrosive fluid that can dissolve wood, flesh, fabric, and bone.

Stomach acid can do this. It is believable the land-slug-topus can invert its stomach like a starfish and digest a hole in something over several hours. But dissolving stuff on contact is pure fantasy.

> This acid is sticky

Slugs make sticky slime.

> it can crawl up obstacles

Slugs can crawl up walls.

Comment: Thanks very much! I knew about slime molds, but I had no idea that they couldn’t move. This will affect the other Pudding-type monsters I was designing.

Comment: @Jobah_HigherMind They can move a little more than plants can move. You will not notice them moving with the naked eye.