# Which animals are closest to a squid monster that mimics humans and other animals?

Tags: creature-design, mythical-creatures

Welcome back to Algennon, where monsters, old feuds between the Five Peoples, and internal political strife mean that heroes are always needed. This is another question about the feasibility of a Pudding-type monster: large mollusks with distinct, somewhat appealing aromas and dangerously unique natural weapons. See [these](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/240247/feasibility-of-an-electric-land-slime) [questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/239198/can-my-pea-soup-slime-monster-exist?noredirect=1&lq=1) for more on the Pudding type. This Pudding, the Vanilla Pudding, is a little trickier to make feasible based on Earth organisms, because… well, you’ll see.

The Vanilla Pudding is very different from its fellows. Whereas the Peasouper emits corrosive acid and dwells in the forests, the Licorice Pudding can electrocute its foes and dwells by the sea, and the Farm Slime can camouflage itself and dwells in the mountains, the Vanilla Pudding can be everywhere. Why? Well, every Pudding can reproduce normally, but they are also created from water, when that water undergoes certain conditions (which I am calling Hydrogenesis). For the Vanilla Pudding, the water has to have been the cause of death for a non-aqueous animal. The Pudding will form in a shape roughly similar to that animal. Like, if your beloved cat Geoffrey drowns trying to catch a bream, a Vanilla Pudding shaped like a cat might emerge from the pool, rudely interrupting your period of mourning. While their mimicry might sort of work in the dark (“Oh, the crude silhouette of a deer, I’m gonna go back to sleep.”) but, when you actually look at them in the light, their mimicry is blatant (“That was no deer, that was a whitish mollusk with tentacles positioned similarly to a deer’s horns and legs”). My question: **are there any Earth creatures similar to this that make the Vanilla Pudding more feasible?**

Comment: Please remember to make your title question and body text question match. We just had a question closed due to reactions to the title question, which wasn't exactly what the OP was asking about. You have the same kind of problem. (Besides, the feasibility of a creature on your imaginary world is always "yes.")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Mimic Octopus**

Some octopussesses can position their tentacles so they look like something other than an octopus. [For example a flat fish.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRknwyEtqxw)

[image]

Not fooling anyone at this resolution. But through some murky water you might see a flounder and not an octopus with its tentacles splayed out.

[This octopus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_wgla5smg64) is pretending to be a coconut

[image]

This is a mollusc that can "sort of" mimic the shape of other animals. Octopussesses are also known to change color if that helps camouflage.

Comment: Brilliant! I didn’t know that one of the two creatures all Puddings are based on naturally had this ability. Thanks so much.